# Proof that the barycentric subdivision of a simplicial complex decreases the diameter of its simplexes.

Tags: simplicial-complex, barycentric-coordinates

I need help with a result about barycentric subdivision someone already asked about [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113537/barycentric-subdivisions-of-simplices-yield-a-simplicial-complex). However, the part I've been struggling with is the one the original poster saw as trivial, statement (c).

The idea is the following: given a simplicial complex $K$ of dimension $n$ and $K^1$ its first barycentric subdivision, the diameter of any simplex of $K^1$ is, at most, $\frac{n}{n+1}$ times as large as the diameter of the largest simplex in $K$.

I've been following the proof in the following book (it's Lemma 6.4):

*Armstrong, M.A.*, Basic topology., Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics. New York etc.: Springer-Verlag. xii, 251 p. DM 69.00 (1990). [ZBL0711.55001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0711.55001).

The author states that the diameter of a simplex is the length of its longest edge. Then, as a consequence of one of the previous statements, proves that any edge $\sigma$ of $K^1$ has two barycenters as its endpoints, say the barycenter of $A$ and the barycenter of $B$, where $B$ is a face of $A$. As a result, the edge is fully contained in $A$ and its barycenter is one of its end-points. The other must be a point in the boundary of $A$.

And this is the step I have trouble with. He states that:
$$\text{length}(\sigma)\leqslant\frac{k}{k+1}\text{diameter}(A)$$
where $k$ is the dimension of $A$.

This step must be really easy but I can't seem to prove it. If someone could lend a hand I'd be very grateful!

### Short Version:

I need to prove that the distance from the barycentre of any $k$-simplex $A$ to a point of its boundary is $\leqslant \frac{k}{k+1}\text{diameter}(A)$.

Comment: Poirot would have known. The little grey cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to prove it when $\sigma$ goes from the barycenter of $A$ to one of the vertices of $A$. Let the vertices be $x_0,\ldots,x_k$ with barycenter $b=\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{i=0}^k x_i$. Then

$$\|b-x_0\| = \|\frac{1}{k+1}\sum_{i=1}^k (x_i-x_0)\|\leq \frac{k}{k+1}\max_i\|x_i-x_0\|.$$

Comment: Wow, thanks! However, how could I prove that the vertices are indeed the points farthest away from the barycenter? In other words, why does it suffice to prove it for the vertices?

Comment: If the distance from $b$ to $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ is at most $d$, then the distance from $b$ to any convex combination $\sum_it_ix_i$, where $\sum t_i=1$ satisfies

$$\|b-\sum t_ix_i\|=\|\sum t_i(b-x_i)\|\leq \sum t_id = d.$$

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! Everything's clear now.